# How to use mouseover for <a> with desktop and touch devices

Tags: jquery, touch, mouseover, desktop, mouseout

I am not able how to get overcome with touch devices and desktops for `mouseover` jQuery with

My **html** code is

```
<li class="odd" onmouseout="hide_product_details_fun(<?php echo $product->id; ?>)" onmouseover="show_product_details_fun(<?php echo $product->id; ?>)">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url($product->slug); ?>"> 
        <img src="image.png" /></a>
</li>
```

and my **jQuery** code is

```
function show_product_details_fun(product_id){
    $('#show_product_details_'+product_id).show();
}

function hide_product_details_fun(product_id){
    $('#show_product_details_'+product_id).hide();
}
```

When I mouseover on

then it shows it's details and when mouseout it hides the detail. It is working perfect on desktop but it is creating problem on `touchpad` devices when I put my finger on

or  instead of triggering function it redirects to  since inside

there is

Please help how to get work with this.I need when I put finger on my img it shows it's details and when I clicked on it then it redirects to it's href.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **[vmouseover](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseover/)** for that. It will support in both desktop and touch devices.

```
$(".odd").vmouseover(function(){
//show details
```

});

```
$(".odd").vmouseout(function(){
//Hide details
});
```

Comment: I used it but it is not working.Do I need to use //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: @user3110655:you need to add jquery mobile library for that. You can download it from http://jquerymobile.com/.

See this for demos-http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: no its not working at all.I included 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

and my code is
 $('.li_details').on('vmouseover touchend',function(){
  var product_id = $(this).attr('rel');
  show_product_details_fun(product_id);
  });
  
  
  $('.li_details').on('vmouseleave touchend',function(){
  var product_id = $(this).attr('rel');
  hide_product_details_fun(product_id);
  });

Comment: @user3110655:can you create a fiddle for same??

Comment: Sorry dude actually I don't know how to create fiddle. can you please create fiddle for me for vmouseover and vmouseleave. Till then I also try to create fiddle.Thanks